# what are the mechanics of sweating?

Tags: physiology, human-anatomy

The causes of sweating aside, i.e. I'm not interested in which and how nerve signals are transmitted to sweat glands. But I would like to read a detailed account on what a sweat gland consists of, what it does when not sweating, but esp. what happens when a sweat nerve signal arrives. Is there a good free review or can you give one?

Comment: Go to the International Hyperhidrosis Society's website www.SweatHelp.org and look in the Know Sweat section. If you don't find what you want there, ask their top docs: Dee Anna Glaser, MD at St Louis University; or David Pariser, MD at Eastern Virginia Medical School.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Myoepithelial cell contraction initiates glandular release from most exocrine glands developed from the ectoderm. These are the cells that exist in the glandular epithelium.

At the distal end of the glanduar coil, an isotonic plasma filtrate gets actively transported into its lumen. As you move down the coil, close to where it connects to the duct, absorptive cells remove NaCl to make sure the sweat is hypotonic when it reaches the surface of the skin. If you view these cells where staining for alpha tubulin or beta actin, you will see they have abundant levels of myofillaments, something uncharacteristic of epithelial cells. Hence Myoepithelial.